# Where are errors logged when a DeployR script is called remotely?

Tags: r, deployr

I am trying to debug my deployR script which gives a generic error "HTTP 400 Error" / "Bad Request" at the Web application end when it fails.

Is there a way to get DeployR to pass a more informative error to the web application. i.e. Typically whatever error message the underlying R program has thrown at Deployr?

If I do a local execution then DeployR does log these messages to the Console pane. But if the script is called Remotely where does it log these errors? Even if I have a deployr Session open simultaneously the Console does not seem to show anything.

Any ideas or Workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

There is an API to retrieve console output. See https://deployr.revolutionanalytics.com/documents/dev/api-doc/guide/workingprojects.html#projectexecuteconsole